# C# Select in SQL Server just using the Date with sql parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime, sqlparameter

I am currently trying to do a `Select` in my SQL Server database using a parameter with `Datetime` type. But I need this parameter only has the format `YYYY-MM-DD` date because of the following query in SQL I'm using and it's working :

```
select 
    idCliente, DescCliente, DescAnalista , StatusChamado , DataAtendimento 
from 
    Atendimento 
where 
    cast ([DataAtendimento] as date) = '2016-04-27';
```

I read several posts indicating that I use `DbType` or `.ToString` but when running it is generating error alleging failure to convert the string to the date / time format.

This is how I use the `SqlParameter`:

```
DateTime date;
date = Data;

try
{
    sqlClient.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adate", date);
    sqlClient.Command.CommandText = @" select idCliente, DescCliente, DescAnalista , StatusChamado , DataAtendimento from Atendimento where cast ([DataAtendimento] as date) = '@adate';";
```

I need a help from you guys , I'm not finding any means that can perform this select

Comment: Remove the `''` in `= '@adate';`.

Comment: I can not believe I was arrested hours because of these quotes , it worked perfectly , thank you

Comment: We've all been there. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove the `''` in `= '@adate'`. With the `''` in place, it effectively turns your query into:

```
select 
    idCliente, DescCliente, DescAnalista , StatusChamado , DataAtendimento 
from Atendimento 
where cast ([DataAtendimento] as date) = '@date';
```

This means that `cast([DateAtendimento] as date)` is compared against the string `'@date'`, thus the conversion to date error.

Comment: That was exactly what was happening, I do not think I was hours researching and trying to convert the date thinking that the problem was it , thank you for help